# Statistic table

Tags: sql, oracle

I made an edit. I wonder what would be the best way of storing and viewing entries when i wish to have a customergroup in the column as well. Would it be still posiible to store a values like you sugessted and make a simple view?

Here the edited question:
I wish to have a statistic table in oracle.
The table should look like this:
EDIT

| Year | Customer |  | Jan | Feb | ... | Dec |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Customer1 | Article1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer1 | Article2 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer1 | Sum | 2 | 2 | ... | 2 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| 2023 | Customer2 | Article1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer2 | Article2 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer2 | Sum | 2 | 2 | ... | 2 |
| 2023 | Customer3 | Article1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer3 | Article2 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer3 | Sum | 2 | 2 | ... | 2 |
| 2023 | CustomerGroup | Article1 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | CustomerGroup | Article2 | 1 | 1 | ... | 1 |
| 2023 | CustomerGroup | Sum | 2 | 2 | ... | 2 |

CustomerGroup could be for example a Group of Customer3 , Customer4 and Customer5.
I wonder what is the best way to store such table. I mean is it better to create exactly a table like above or can reach the goal with a view?

But what would be the best way of storing the values in table(s) and how should the view be created? Or is there any better way for things like that?

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your existing tables; an English (not code) description of the logic you want to implement; **YOUR** attempt at a solution; and the issues/errors with **YOUR** solution. If you don't tell us what you are starting with how can we get to a solution that is relevant to your application?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From my point of view, table should not look like that. You *would* present it to users in such a tabular form as it is easier to read, but - to store data into a table, I'd suggest something like this:

```
create table statistic
  (statistic_id number primary key,
   customer_id  number    constraint fk_st_cust references customer,
   article      varchar2(20),
   year         number(4),
   month        number(2) constraint ch_st_mon check (month between 1 and 12),
   amount       number
  );
```

I don't know what values actually represent (should `article` be a foreign key to another table? What is `amount`?) nor which constraints should be applied to it (for example, is year 2854 valid? Can amount be negative?). How many rows can you have per month/year/customer?

View would then be

```
create or replace view v_statistic as
  select c.customer_name, 
         s.year, 
         s.article,
         sum(case when month =  1 then s.amount else 0 end) january,
         sum(case when month =  2 then s.amount else 0 end) february,
         ...
         sum(case when month = 12 then s.amount else 0 end) december
  from statistic s join customer c on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
  group by c.customer_name, s.year, s.article
```

That might need to be modified depending on actual data and requirement, but - shortly - that's how I would do it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use conditional aggregation with `ROLLUP`:

```sql
CREATE VIEW table_name_statistics (year, username, type, jan, feb, mar) AS
SELECT EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime) AS year,
       username,
       CASE
       WHEN GROUPING_ID(type) = 1
       THEN 'sum'
       ELSE type
       END AS type,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) = 1 THEN 1 END), 0) AS jan,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) = 2 THEN 1 END), 0) AS feb,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN EXTRACT(MONTH FROM datetime) = 3 THEN 1 END), 0) AS mar
FROM   table_name t
GROUP BY
       EXTRACT(YEAR FROM datetime),
       username,
       ROLLUP(type)
ORDER BY
       year,
       username,
       t.type NULLS LAST
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (datetime, username, type) AS
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'Customer1', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01', 'Customer1', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-01', 'Customer1', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'Customer1', 'Article2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01', 'Customer1', 'Article2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-01', 'Customer1', 'Article2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'Customer2', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-02-01', 'Customer2', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-01', 'Customer2', 'Article1' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-01-01', 'Customer2', 'Article2' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT DATE '2023-03-01', 'Customer2', 'Article2' FROM DUAL;
```

Then the view outputs:

| YEAR | USERNAME | TYPE | JAN | FEB | MAR |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2023 | Customer1 | Article1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer1 | Article2 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer1 | sum | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 2023 | Customer2 | Article1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer2 | Article2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2023 | Customer2 | sum | 2 | 1 | 2 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/1gkGKOrK)